# how to delete a database manually in oracle?

Tags: database-administration

How do i delete database manually. Is tehre any commands for deleting a database? I usually connect through VNC but its better if there is any command line tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running at least 10g you can use the drop database command.
You can find an example [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/AlejandroVargas/2007/03/10g_drop_database_command.html).

Comment: I'm using oracle 9 db.. if not `drop database` command, can i delete the files manually and expect it to be dropped?

Comment: Yes. That is all any process is going to do.  They just have how to find all the files build in to dbca and "drop database".  By definition an oracle database is the files(data files,temp files,redo logs,control files).